# Use OIDC Password Grant with MFA

Tags: authentication, session, openid-connect, onelogin

https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/api/password-grant

I'm trying to hit the password_grant flow. However when I hit for for a user configured with MFA I get presented with the an error of

```
{
"error": "invalid_request",
"error_description": "MFA is required for this user"}
```

Is there anyway to do the password grant flow so other clients like web and mobile can hit the endpoint without having to resort to the auth flow?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. Use of this grant type is not recommended for precisely this reason - you cannot do MFA (unless purely via a side channel like a push notification), consent or federation.

This article sums up the problem:
https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications